# Passing JVM Properties Contains Space in Dockerfile CMD Command

Tags: java, docker, jvm

I have this CMD in my Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar xxx.jar"]
```

And I want to add parameter below to $JAVA_OPTS

```
-Dproducer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=xxx password=pass;
```

Because it contains space I couldn't suceeded (application is not started). How can I pass jvm parameter which contains space to use it in CMD in DockerFile?

Comment: (You can write `CMD java $JAVA_OPTS ...` and it will mean exactly the same thing – Docker inserts the `sh -c` wrapper for you – but that won't solve this shell-quoting problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Either remove ENTRYPOINT and use CMD as David suggested, or provide a shell script wrapper that better handles your $JAVAOPTS variable content.